# Destructure a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, code-structure

The problem set :
[Letter combinations of a phone](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/)

The solution I had in mind:

```
def letterCombinations(self, digits: str) -> List[str]:
    if not digits: return []
    digit_map = {'2': 'abc', '3': 'def', '4': 'ghi', '5': 'jkl', '6': 'mno', 
                 '7': 'pqrs', '8': 'tuv', '9': 'wxyz'}
    result = [""]
    arr = []
    for i in digits:
        for j in digit_map:
            if i==j:
                s = map(str,digit_map[i])
                for x in s:
                    arr.append(x)
```

After this I was going to use the map() function on arr and then match one alphabet to another. However, this though process was not good enough.
I turned to solutions thereafter.
The solution I liked best was
[this one](https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/discuss/467494/17-Letter-Combinations-of-a-Phone-Number-Py-All-in-One-By-Talse)
However, in the solution that's provided :

```
def letterCombinations(self, digits: str) -> List[str]:
    if not digits: return []
    dt = {'2': 'abc', '3': 'def', '4': 'ghi', '5': 'jkl', '6': 'mno', '7': 'pqrs', '8': 'tuv', '9': 'wxyz'}
    rst = ['']
    for i in digits: rst = [j+k for j in rst for k in dt[i]]
    return rst
```

I do not understand the for loop on line 5. Could someone destructure it and write it in multiple lines so that the output doesn't change.

I tried to do it myself but the output changed and gave wrong results.

```
for i in digits:
    tmp = []
    for j in rst:
        for k in dt[i]:
            temp = [j+k] 
    rst += temp
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the example input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is called list comprehensions. You can read more about it here
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

That piece can be replaced with these nested for loops

```
new_rst = []
for j in rst:
  for k in dt[i]:
    new_rst.append(j+k)

rst = new_rst
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It works well and good and it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your own code had some minor issues, apart from not working:

- the first parameter is `self`, suggesting this would be the method of some object, but you're presenting it as a function (and it doesn't actually reference `self` either)?
- the name `letterCombinations` isn't the best, `letter_combinations` would be better in standard Python, but perhaps that's a requirement of your assignment?
- your function didn't actually return anything, so even if it worked, you wouldn't be able to tell (note how the found solution does have a `return` statement)

The reason the code you found works:

```
for i in digits: rst = [j+k for j in rst for k in dt[i]]
```

This loops over each digit character `i` in `digits`. For each one, it defines the result `rst` to be a list of every string `j` already in `rst`, combined with every character `k` of the string `dt[i]`, which are the letters corresponding to the digit.

For example, if the function would be called as `letterCombinations('12')`, this would happen:

- first character is `1`, so `i` equals `'1'` during the first iteration.
- `rst` contains a single empty string, so each character of `dt['1']` is added to that, and the resulting list `['a', 'b', 'c']` is assigned to `rst`
- the second character is `2`, so `i` equals `'2'` during the second iteration.
- each character of `dt['2']` will now be added to every string already in `rst`, so `rst` will become `['ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', ... , 'cf']`

Which is exactly what's needed. The resulting `rst` is returned after the loop completes its final iteration with `return rst`.

Note that the part `[j+k for j in rst for k in dt[i]]` is a so-called list comprehension, which is different from the normal for-loop around it. It creates a list of `j+k` for each value of `j` in `rst`, for each value of `k` in `dt[i]`.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your answer. The detailed explanation is very much appreciated. I can't accept both the answers and the "de-list comprehension (per say)" was what I was looking for. I have upvoted it as deserved.

Comment: That's alright - keep in mind that comprehension are often the better choice for both readability and speed, although they may take some getting used to when coming to Python from other languages.